# Best practice to parse xml file with same content but based on different schemas

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse xml files from two sources. Both xml files contain the same content but each source uses their own schemas. This means the values that i want to extract from the xml file will be stored in different element names depending on the source of the file.

Here is an example - Assume i am only interested in the "name" of a product.

```
Source 1
-------------------------
    <item>
     <itemname>Camera</itemname>
     <itemprice>20</itemprice>
    </item>

Source 2
-------------------------
    <productList>
     <productName>Camera</productname>
     <ProductPrice>20</productprice>
    </productList>
```

To parse the above i have to know the source of the xml file and then either do a

```
getElementsByTagName("itemname");
```

or

```
getElementsByTagName("productName");
```

My original plan was to have a different parser for each source's xml file but i am thinking that maybe i could write a generic parser if i specify the path to the element i need. The benefit of this is that i can then process any xml file from any source without having to modify the parser.

What i am thinking of doing is to store the path to the element on to a properties file. i.e.

```
source1.name="itemname"
source2.name=productName
```

The generic parser would then just retrieve the element based on the name i provide it. This will probably work but i am thinking that if i am interested in more than one element it might be cumbersome to maintain it via a properties file.

Is there a better way to resolve the above? Please note that One restriction that i am limited to is that the target platform for this is JDK 1.4 so xpath etc would not work.

Comment: There is no such thing as multi-word element names. The xml you've provided is invalid.

Comment: Ok that was just an example...

Comment: It's best to use somewhat valid examples. Otherwise they confuse folks and distract from the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution is XPath. No matter how different the XML inputs are, you can store an XPath for each as a string in a properties file. There are several XPath-compliant parsers that work with JDK 1.4.

Comment: Hi could u give an example of which I can use. I would like to avoid having to add new libraries if possible

Comment: xpath is available in the jdk  http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml

Comment: No its not for jdk1.4 - see my original post. 
This is actually quite confusing. According to this site http://www.esus.com/javaindex/j2se/jdk1.2/jaxp/jaxp.html JAXP is included in jdk 1.4

Comment: JAXP defines an interface. You also need an implementation, and unfortunately an XPath implementation (javax.xml.xpath) wasn't bundled in the JDK until 1.5. However, you can download implementations like Xalan which implement javax.xml.xpath for 1.4+.

Comment: Ok so if i download the xalan library i should be able to use xpath?

Comment: Thanks i managed to use Xpath by downloading the JDOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

If element names follow a convention (*Name, *Price), you could write a generic parsing function using wildcards and XPath. Or you could write it based on tag orders if they are always the same (you can do this without XPath).

Comment: No they dont follow the convention name. In fact in some cases the element name is alphanumeric with numbers.

Comment: What about tag order? `rootNode.getChildren()[0] = "name"` etc.

Comment: No not even tag order. One of them contains a header sections with lots of other information.